# Make samples using videos

Tags: sample

I'm currently looking for make engine sounds samples using YouTube videos.

Do you think is possible to sample this type of video? (Ex

at 0:20 or 0:35)

I think the best possibility is to wait a stable rpm, take the audio and make a seamless sound (sounds like a wave but this is not a problem).

Sorry for those type of question but I'm very newbie in this domain :/
Thanks !

Comment: What's the application? What are you doing this for? Where will the sounds be used?

Comment: I have Audacity. For a bus simulator

Answer (score 1):

OK for a bus simulator you would probably want to try a parameterised procedural approach to generating the audio. This may involved using samples but would more likely use synthesis. The tone of the engine would change dramatically with different RPM levels, and also the external sound you hear would also change dependent on road-conditions as well so there are many layers involved in getting this right.